# how to find object of min value of key2 from list of max values of key1 in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, max, min

I have a list of dictionary objects like `[{'year':2017,'q':2,'category'=c}]` which each of objects have 3 fields as the following:

```
[{2015,1,w}
{2015,3,q}
{2017,2,a}
{2012,5,b}
{2017,5,p}
{2013,3,a}
{2015,4,a}
{2017,1,d}
{2016,2,e}
]
```

how can i sort the list firstly by max year and then between the max years objects, i want to find the object whch have min key2 value. actually firstly i wan to sort the list based on two keys(max key1 then min key2) to have the following list:

```
[{2017,1,d}
{2017,2,a}
{2017,5,p}
{2016,4,e}
{2015,1,w}
{2015,3,q}
{2015,4,a}
{2013,3,a}
{2012,5,b}]
```

finally return `{2017,1,d}` from the list

Comment: `{2015,1,w}` - this is invalid notation. It can not be a dict. Maybe, you meant tuples. Anyway, you should update your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set` is unordered, so I suppose that you want to sort list of lists, you can use `sorted()` to do this:

> Starting with `Python 2.4`, both `list.sort()` and `sorted()` added a
>   **key** parameter to specify a function to be called on each list element
>   prior to making comparisons.

```
>>> a=[
...  [2015,1,'w'],
...  [2015,3,'q'],
...  [2017,2,'a'],
...  [2012,5,'b'],
...  [2017,5,'p'],
...  [2013,3,'a'],
...  [2015,4,'a'],
...  [2017,1,'d'],
...  [2016,2,'e']]
>>>
>>> sorted(a,key=lambda x:(-x[0],x[1]))
[[2017, 1, 'd'], [2017, 2, 'a'], [2017, 5, 'p'], [2016, 2, 'e'], [2015, 1, 'w'], [2015, 3, 'q'], [2015, 4, 'a'], [2013, 3, 'a'], [2012, 5, 'b']]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used something like that , but your object must be list:

```
ordered_l =sorted(sorted(your_list,key=itemgetter(1),reverse=False),key=itemgetter(0),reverse=True)
```